# Spring autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 3.0 project that I'm trying to wire up that has a dependency on a library project (also Spring 3.0) which has several classes that have properties being injected via **org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value**.

I do not need the classes with injected properties to be loaded nor the properties to be injected.  I only need one specific class to be autowired from the library project.

I keep getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.example.library.controller.App.dir; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.achDir'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.achDir'
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:713)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 40 more
```

Here is the snippet of my applicationContext.xml.  I have tried several versions of the following but the exclusions/inclusion filters do not appear to work.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.library" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>     
</context:component-scan>
```

I am using a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as suggested by one of the answers, this already existed in my project.  Also, I have removed all of the component-scan and annotation-config from my Spring config files.

```
<!-- Define the other the old-fashioned way, with 'ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders' set to TRUE -->  
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>src/test/resources/my.properties</value>
            <value>my.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I should add that this error occurs while running a unit test that extends a super class with the following annotations:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true,transactionManager="txManager")
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
public abstract class BaseTest {
```

Comment: If you tell me which library maybe i could help. The error is really strange

Comment: May be is better option to declare the bean that you need instead of scan

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your configuration, but maybe your failing class `com.example.library.controller.App` suggests that the App class is annotated with `@Controller`, not `@Service`, so you may have to change the expression in `<context:exclude-filter...` Anyway, I would have solved the Problem using a property source with a "don't care" value for `app.achDir`, since you don't use it (and the bean) anyway

Comment: How do you write your `@Value`? Do you have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: @ Jose,  I will try that tomorrow but I'm certain that even when I don't do a scan I still receive the error message.

Comment: @madhead Please see update to question

Comment: can you post content of your property files. it seem there is no property called app.achDir.

Comment: @erencan That's the point, there is no property, I do not want the bean referencing that property to be loaded, and therefore I don't want to have to add the property to my properties file.

Comment: @JaredKnipp as far as i understand, you set several proporty files to the spring context like my.properties and you try to inject app.achDir. if app.achDir is not a property then what is it? what is its context ?

Comment: It is a property, I do not want the class the references it to be loaded/scanned and therefore the property to be injected. I want it to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a very simple solution that I overlooked.  My library project jar was including its applicationContext.xml and I didn't realize it.  I removed that, rebuilt the jar and its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single component from that library, then it's probably better to define it explicitly. For example:

```
<bean id="..." class="com.example.library.SomeComponent">
 <!-- Bean initialization -->
</bean>
```

... or using [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).

If you actually need to scan this package, then make sure that all possible cases are handled properly by your exclusion filters. The stack trace suggests, that the component is annotated with @Controller, not @Service. However, there are other options, that should be considered as well, like @Component and @Repository.

Comment: The problem is that even when I do not do a component scan, I still get the error.

Comment: Is the error message exactly the same? 1) Make sure the component isn't picked up by another component-scan (eg. as a "regular" component from your app) 2) Try setting those properties for this component only (use [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)) and see, if anything changes.

Comment: Yes, exact same error.  The project is using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: If you remove _all_ scans from your project and create the component with a simple <bean/> declaration, is the error message still the same? Could you post that <bean /> fragment as well?

Comment: I finally figured out the problem after a teammate got it to work after changing the ContextConfiguration attribute to reference a different location.  Light bulb when on that it was a classpath issue.... My library was included its applicationContext.xml file and I didn't realize it, which was causing the components to still be scanned.  Removed that and its working fine.